# Stack tabs when using Geany

Tags: editors, plugin, productivity, geany, tabs

Is there a way on Geany text editor (Linux) to stack tabs, such that there are multiple rows of tabs?

Issue: Sometimes I have open 30 or so files in Geany. But Geany only shows about 10 on average (based on the size of the file).

Desired solution: Specify in a configuration setting how many levels of tabs for Geany to use. E.g., 1 (default), 2, 3, 4, ... max.

More info: Is there a plugin for this which already exists? If not, how feasible is it to create a plugin for this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can found the tabs configuration in Geany's manual, chapter *[Interface Notebook tab preferences](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#interface-notebook-tab-preferences)*. There is no built-in feature for multi-line tabs.

For your plugin related question, there is no one as you expect in the official plugin page : [plugins.geany.org](https://plugins.geany.org/)